# ASP.NET MVC5 Uploading picture

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

my problem is that I made a web page where I can upload image and create a new recipe (filling textboxes), but the submit button does nothing. Any solutions?

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Recipe", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

     <label for="photo">Upload photo:</label>
     <input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="width: 100%;" />
    ...
     <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    }
```

My Controller look like this:

```
    // GET: Recipe/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var viewModel = new ReceptDTO
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now,
            UserId = userId
        };
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    // POST: Recipe/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(ReceptDTO recipe, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ReceptManager recipes = new ReceptManager();
            recipes.SaveRecept(recipe);
            if (file != null)
            {
                string pic = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(
                       Server.MapPath("~/images/recipes/" + User.Identity.GetUserId()), pic);
                // File uploaded
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        return View(recipe);
    }
```

EDIT: The full view:

```
        @model Receptura_v4.Models.ReceptDTO

        @{
            ViewBag.Title = "Új recept feltöltése";
        }

        <h2>Új recept feltöltése</h2>

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Recipe", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<label for="photo">Fotó feltöltése:</label>
<input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" style="width: 100%;" />


<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Cím:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Adag", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Portion, new { id = "portion", @readonly = "readonly", style = "border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" })
                <div id="slider-range-min"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Elkészítési idő", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Time, new { id = "time", @readonly = "readonly", style = "border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" })
                <div id="slider-range-min2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @*<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Elkészítési idő", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Time, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Time, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    </div>*@

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Kategória", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("Category", new List<SelectListItem>
            {
            new SelectListItem { Text="Levesek", Value = "Levesek"},
            new SelectListItem { Text="Főzelékek", Value = "Főzelékek"},
            new SelectListItem { Text="Desszertek", Value = "Desszertek"},
            new SelectListItem { Text="Egytálételek", Value = "Egytálételek"}
            }, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Elkészítés", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Preparation, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Preparation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Nehézség", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Difficulty, new { id = "amount", @readonly = "readonly", style = "border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" })
                <div id="slider"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @*<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Elkészítési költség", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    </div>*@

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Elkészítési költség", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Price, new { id = "price", @readonly = "readonly", style = "border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" })
                <div id="slider-range-min3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Date)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserId)
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Új hozzávaló", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div>
            <input id="Button1" type="button"
                   value="+" onclick="DynamicDiv();" />
            <div id="foo"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Feltöltés" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
        }

    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                var diff = ["Könnyű", "Közepes", "Nehéz", "Nagyon nehéz"];
                $("#slider").slider({
                    value: 2,
                    min: 1,
                    max: 4,
                    step: 1,
                    slide: function (event, ui) {
                        $("#amount").val(diff[ui.value - 1]);
                    }
                });
                $("#amount").val("Közepes");
            });
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#slider-range-min2").slider({
                    range: "min",
                    value: 5,
                    min: 1,
                    max: 100,
                    slide: function (event, ui) {
                        $("#time").val(ui.value + " fő");
                    }
                });
                $("#time").val($("#slider-range-min2").slider("value") + " fő");
            });
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#slider-range-min").slider({
                    range: "min",
                    value: 30,
                    min: 15,
                    max: 100,
                    slide: function (event, ui) {
                        $("#portion").val(ui.value + " perc");
                    }
                });
                $("#portion").val($("#slider-range-min").slider("value") + " perc");
            });
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#slider-range-min3").slider({
                    range: "min",
                    value: 500,
                    min: 100,
                    max: 10000,
                    slide: function (event, ui) {
                        $("#price").val(ui.value + " Ft");
                    }
                });
                $("#price").val($("#slider-range-min3").slider("value") + " Ft");
            });
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("<div>ASD</div>").appendTo("div#main");
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            function DynamicDiv() {
                var dynDiv = document.createElement("div");
                dynDiv.id = "divDyna";
                dynDiv.innerHTML = "Név:</label><div class=\"col-md-10\"><input class=\"form-control text-box single-line\" id=\"Preparation\" name=\"Preparation\" type=\"text\" value=\"\" /><span class=\"field-validation-valid text-danger\" data-valmsg-for=\"Preparation\" data-valmsg-replace=\"true\"></span></div></div>"
                //dynDiv.innerHTML = "<div class=\"form-group\"><label class=\"control-label col-md-2\" for=\"Elk_sz_t_s\">Név</label><div class=\"col-md-10\"><input class=\"form-control text-box single-line\" id=\"Preparation\" name=\"Preparation\" type=\"text\" value=\"\" /><span class=\"field-validation-valid text-danger\" data-valmsg-for=\"Preparation\" data-valmsg-replace=\"true\"></span></div></div>"
                //dynDiv.innerHTML = "<label>Név: <input type='text'>";
                dynDiv.className = 'form-group control-label col-md-2';
                document.getElementById("foo").appendChild(dynDiv);
            }
        </script>
    }
```

Comment: When you say does nothing? Do you mean nothing happens at all on page or no data is saved? is the page re-loaded?

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint into your Create action to see if this is being called?

Comment: Nothing happens when i click the submit button.

Comment: Might be worth taking a look at the generated html (View Source) + post it back here.

Comment: The Create POST action is not being called..

Comment: If the submit button isn't submitting the form the presumably either there's something wrong with the HTML or there's JavaScript capturing and canceling the click and/or post event.  Can you show the complete HTML form?  Is there any JavaScript running?  (If you disable JavaScript in the browser, does the submit button post the form?)  Are there any console errors in the browser?

Comment: its not a good suggestion but it happened once to me change the name and id of inputtype file as something else..i changed to file1 here and try...<input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" style="width: 100%;" /> if not helping post the entire view code

Comment: View the full code of the view

Comment: Full code of the view added.